# Perform JSR 303 validation in transactional service call

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions, bean-validation, jooq

I am using the play framework to develop a web application which accesses a postgres db using JOOQ and spring transactions.

Currently I am implementing the user signup which is structured in the following way:

1. The user posts the signup form
2. The request is routed to a controller action which maps all parameters like e-mail, password etc. on a DTO. The different fields of the DTO are annotated with JSR 303 constraints.

   The e-mail field is annotated with a constraint validator that makes sure that the same address is not added twice. This validator has an autowired reference to the `UserRepository`, so that it can invoke it's `isExistingEmail` method.
3. The signup method of the user service is called, which basically looks as follows:

   ```
   @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
   public User signupUser(UserDto userDto) {
       validator.validate(userDto);
       userRepository.add(userDto);
       return tutor;
   }
   ```

In case of a validation error the `validator.validate(userDto)` call inside of the service will throw a RuntimeException.

Please note that the repository's `add` method is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)` while the `isExistingEmail` method does not have any annotations.

My problem is that when I post the signup form twice in succession, I receive a unique constraint error from the database since both times the `userRepository.isExistingEmail` call returns false. However, what I would expect is that the second signup call is not allowed to add the user to the repository, as I set the isolation level of the transaction to serializable.

Is this the expected behavior or might there be a JOOQ/spring transactions configuration issue?

I added a `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` call in the service to make sure a transaction is actually active. So this part seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and reading the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) on transaction isolation in the postgres manual I have come to realize that my understanding of spring managed transactions was just lacking.

When setting the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` postgres won't really block any concurrent transactions. Instead it will make use of predicate locks to monitor if a committed transaction would produce a result that is different than actually running concurrent transactions one after another.

An exception will only be thrown by the underlying database driver if the state of the data is not valid when the second transaction tries to commit. I was able to verify this behavior and to force a serialization failure by temporarily removing the unique constraint on my e-mail field.

My final solution was to reduce the isolation level to `READ_COMMITTED` and to handle the unique constraint violation exception when invoking `userRepository.add(userDto)`, since a `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level is not really necessary to deal with this particular use case.

Please let me know of any better ways of dealing with this kind of standard situation.